# How to create a calculated column if the field has choices?

Tags: sharepoint-online

If Category is US Support Service and Designation is Supervisor & below =1000;
If the category is APAC Support Service/SSC and designation is Supervisor & below   = 500

Category and Designation has choice field

Comment: Can you please add your conditions for calculation in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choice fields are essentially just text fields with predefined options. Try just making the calculated column as if these were just text boxes:

```
=IF(
    [Designation]="Supervisor & below",
    IF(
        [Category]="US Support Service",
        1000,
        IF(
            [Category]="APAC Support Service/SSC",
            500
        )
    )
)
```

I don't know how well calculated columns agree with special characters, so you might have to change `&` to `and` and maybe `/` to `or` or something like that. But the above statement should say "If the designation is *Supervisor & below* then check the category. Otherwise leave blank. If the category was *US Support Service*, put 1000. Otherwise if Category is *APAC Support Service/SSC* put 500. If it's neither of them, leave the field blank.